# Changing labels and colors of slope map values in ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, slope

I have this code in ArcMap which produces a slope map with the correct values (the slope map is reclass.tif), but I want its labels that appear in the Table of Contents underneath it to show differently, as well as its colors. This is how it appears when it is produces from the Python script:

[image]

Instead of the labels being 1 - 6 and the colors being a random mix of colors, I want it to show as the following:

[image]

Is there a way of doing this with ArcPy?

Code:

```
def main():
    import arcpy
    from arcpy.sa import *
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ArcMap_Folder"
    inRaster = "USGS_13_n37w082_20220512.tif"

    outSlope = Slope(inRaster, "PERCENT_RISE")
    outSlope.save("C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ArcMap_Folder\\slope.tif")

    myRemapRange = RemapRange([[0, 3.99, 1], [4, 9.99, 2], [10, 15.99, 3], [16, 30.99, 4], [31, 60.99, 5], [61, 999999, 6]])
    outReclassRR = Reclassify(outSlope, "VALUE", myRemapRange,"NODATA" )
    outReclassRR.save("C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ArcMap_Folder\\reclass.tif")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think what you want to do is to change the symbology labels. You could create a reference symbology layer and copy it using "ApplySymbologyFromLayer".

Comment: Thank you for the help!